# Feincms ApplicationContent overwrite context

Tags: python, django, feincms

If I add `ApplicationContent` to a region on a feincms page, how do I update the `feincms_page's` context?

> **Use case**
>
> Changing a feincms_page's title to the application content's title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fragment` [templatetag](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/api/templatetags.html)

**app template:**

```
{% fragment request "frag_title" %} my title {% endfragment %}
```

**inherited template:**

```
{% if request|has_fragment:"frag_title" %}
    <title>{% get_fragment request "frag_title" %}</title>
{% else %}
    <title>{{ feincms_page.title }}</title>
{% endif %}
```